# Javascript: How to add array values to object property

Tags: javascript

Following code is for socket.io server in node.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var clients=[];
var gamename={};

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('game', function(data){
    gamename[data.gamename]=data.number; //problem is here 
  });
});
```

gamename=name of the game;
number= user id;

1. there can be more number of games;
2. there can be more number of users per game

and I am emitting game event in the client side with some data (includeing gamename, and number)whenever a connection is established with the server. So whenever a new client connects to the server the game event is triggered in the server. In the game event in the server side I want to push "number" to the object property gamename(variable).

example:

```
var games={};
```

whenever there is a connection for example for the game poker with user id 34
I want to do 
     var gamename='poker';

```
 gamename[gamename] -> I want this automatically created as array, or   anything, but I want to push user id's.
```

the resulting objecting should be.

```
games={'poker' : [34]};
```

If I one more user connects for poker with user id 45,

```
games={'poker' : [34, 45]};
```

and If a a user connects for game cricket with user 67

```
games={'poker' : [34, 45],'cricket' : [67]};
```

Initial object

```
games={};
```

after some connections(there can be n number of connections)

```
games={'poker' : [34, 45],'cricket' : [67]};
```

If my question is not clear I will explain it in detail if anybody asks.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var clients=[];
var gamename={};

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('game', function(data){
    gamename[data.gamename] = gamename[data.gamename] || [];
    gamename[data.gamename].push( data.number ); //no more problem 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, But could you please explain what this line does gamename[data.gamename] = gamename[data.gamename] || []; I am new to javascript

Comment: it initializes the gamename[data.gamename] to an empty array if it's not already initialized.

Comment: yw, please accept my answer if it solved your problem :)